# Defining application scopes in AAD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

It seems there are two separate mechanisms for defining applications scopes in AAD: appRoles via manifest update and oauth2Permissions via App Registrations, Exposed API tab. The first one is the only one allowing an application scope (allowedMemberType: Application) - the API permissions tab in App Registrations seems only to allow delegated user permissions. Am I interpreting this correctly? It seems rather confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**appRoles via manifest**

We can define both User role and Application role via manifest. We can see application roles under application permissions. And application permission is used by client credential flow.

We can not find the user roles under delegated user permissions since these roles are not used here. The roles is assigned to specific user under enterprise app tab, the developer need to grant different logic code for different roles.

**oauth2Permissions via App Registrations**

We can only add delegated permission here. And this permission applies to all the users, not specific user. When users sign in, they will be asked to consent to the permissions.

Comment: Sorry, but you are repating my own statement: I know that via appRoles I can define an Application permission. What's confusing is that that permission is exposed as an alternative to available Delegated permission (as per ur snippet above), which is not defined via appRoles but via oauth2permissions.User roles defined via appRoles are not exposed through available permissions UI at all, only through user assignments to an app in Enterprise Apps.

Comment: @Marc See the updated answer. Hope this will make it clear.